# Use RadioButtons within one activity

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiobutton

I am making a quiz app which there are some question:

[image]

When the user clicks `NEXT QUESTION`, another question will be shown.
I have made the current code:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.number_1:
            if (checked)
                point = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+ point,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        case R.id.number_2:
            if (checked)
                point = 1;
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+ point,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        case R.id.number_3:
            if (checked)
                point = 2;
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+ point,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        case R.id.number_4:
            if (checked)
                point = 3;
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+ point,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
    }
}
```

How can I make this scenario happen when the `NEXT QUESTION` clicked, another question pop up in the same activity?

Comment: you just need to add new content to the textview and clear all radio buttons for the next questions

Comment: I suggest u to use viewpager, where u can have multiple pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** If you are using `RadioGroup`, then when the `NextQestion` button get clicked first `clear` the state of `RadioButton` calling method `RadioGroup.clearCheck()`.

**2.** Get the next `question` from your `database` or from other place and set values to your `TextView` and `RadioButtons`.

**Here is an example:**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textQuestion;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3;
    Button buttonNextQuestion;

    int questionNo = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_question); 
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        buttonNextQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next_question);

        buttonNextQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                questionNo++;
                loadNextQuestion();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadNextQuestion() {

        String question, option1, option2, option3, option4;

        // Get question and options from database or from other place
        // and store into >> question, option1, option2, option3, option4

        // Update UI
        // Clear radio button state
        radioGroup.clearCheck();

        // Set new question and its options to view
        textQuestion.setText(question);
        radioButton1.setText(option1);
        radioButton2.setText(option2);
        radioButton3.setText(option3);
        radioButton4.setText(option4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If my answer seems useful then you can vote it up. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have your questionTextView, just use questionTextView.setText(newQuestion)

Set all your radioButton to false/unselected idk the correct thing.

---

But its probably better to put a FrameLayout in your activity and call a new QuestionFragment every time your user did answer a question and build a new View , your controller will be more independent.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that

```
public void nextQuestion(View view){

   questionTextView.setText(gtString(R.string.nextQuestion));
   checkBox1.setText("option1");
   checkBox2.setText("option2");
   checkBox3.setText("option3");
   checkBox4.setText("option4");
}
```

Replace all above view names with yours